# Programmatically create a post once a day

Tags: wp-insert-post

By following [this howto](https://tommcfarlin.com/programmatically-create-a-post-in-wordpress/), I wanted to create programmatically a post, once a day. Accordingly to the author, the next line will check if a post with a given name already exists:

```
if( null == get_page_by_title( $title ) ) {
    // Create the page
} else {
    // The page exists
} // end if
```

but this doesn't work, because my WP is generating multiple posts with the same title as I added the function to the *functions.php*. The Wordpress Codex [says](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page_by_title) that the `get_page_by_title()`:

> Retrieves a post given its title. If more than one post uses the same
>   title, the post with the smallest ID will be returned.

so, if I understand correcly, the `get_page_by_title( $title )` can't be `null`. What is wrong here?

The full code that I use:

```
/**
 * A function used to programmatically create a post in WordPress. The slug, author ID, and title
 * are defined within the context of the function.
 *
 * @returns -1 if the post was never created, -2 if a post with the same title exists, or the ID
 *          of the post if successful.
 */
function programmatically_create_post() {

    // Initialize the page ID to -1. This indicates no action has been taken.
    $post_id = -1;

    // Setup the author, slug, and title for the post
    $author_id = 1;
    $slug = 'digest-' . date( 'd-m-Y', strtotime( "-1 days" ) );
    $title = 'Digest - ' . date( 'd-m-Y', strtotime( "-1 days" ) );

    // If the page doesn't already exist, then create it
    if( null == get_page_by_title( $title ) ) {

        // Set the post ID so that we know the post was created successfully
        $post_id = wp_insert_post(
            array(
                'comment_status'    =>  'closed',
                'ping_status'       =>  'closed',
                'post_author'       =>  $author_id,
                'post_name'         =>  $slug,
                'post_title'        =>  $title,
                'post_status'       =>  'pending',
                'post_type'         =>  'post'
            )
        );

    // Otherwise, we'll stop
    } else {

            // Arbitrarily use -2 to indicate that the page with the title already exists
            $post_id = -2;

    } // end if

} // end programmatically_create_post
add_filter( 'after_setup_theme', 'programmatically_create_post' );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the documentation for `get_page_by_title`, the 3rd argument is `$post_type, Default: page`. Since you are creating a post, you should pass in `post` as the post type when calling get_page_by_title, like below:

```
if( null == get_page_by_title( $title, OBJECT, 'post' ) )
```